# How many people dance vs how many people do dance

Tags: do

I get confused with this question. I want to ask some questions about a tradtional party.
This party is something like an event, people gather together and wear specific clothes.
Is it correct to ask "how many people dance at the party?" Or it necessarily needs "do"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately, it is not very clear what you are asking. Please [edit] the post to the describe the scenario and what you are trying to ask about, using different words, and why you do or do not think *do* might be required. Both *How many people dance in the party?* and *How many people do dance in the party?* are grammatical, but they would also both be very strange to hear except in some narrow circumstances, not least because *party* has different meanings. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Hi. I've just edited the text and I tried to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using party to mean the same thing as "celebration" and not "a group of people" (e.g. a wedding party). If so, it should be "at the party", not "in the party".

If the party is over, it should be:
"How many people danced at the party?"

If the party is currently happening, it should be:
"How many people are dancing at the party?"

If the party has not happened yet, it should be:
"How many people will dance at the party?"

Only if the party is a regular event that has happened multiple times and will happen again in the future, it should be:
"How many people dance at the party?"

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your explanation. I've changed the proposition, as you said it should be "at". And I explained why I used simple present tense.